# MySQL, Inserting data into multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to insert data from one table into another. I would like to put the info from `unit_66` in one column and the info for `unit_166` into another column but I'm having trouble using two SELECT statements, I get this error when executing the code:

```
[Err] 1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

CREATE TABLE time_test (unit_66 BIGINT, unit_116 BIGINT);

insert into time_test (unit_66, unit_116)
VALUES 
(
(select time_stamp from `events` where unit_id = 66 LIMIT 50),

(select time_stamp from `events` where unit_id = 116 LIMIT 50)
);
```

Can anyone tell what the problem it is?

Comment: Why are you using limit 50?

Comment: Time_stamp is huge im just limiting it to 50 rows until i can get it to work.

Comment: That is your problem, the way it is written, it expects one value, not 50 rows of values.

Comment: how do i properly limit it then?

Comment: Gordon answered it for you.

Answer (score 4):

I think you want `insert . . . select`.  You are using a scalar subquery, but having it return up to 50 values.  That is causing your error.  If you had a `limit 1` in each subquery, then it would work.

It is a little hard to guess what you are trying to do, but let me try:

```
insert into time_test(unit_66, unit_116)
    select e66.time_stamp, e116.timestamp
    from events e66 join
         events e116
         on e66.unit_id = 66 and e116.unit_id = 116
    order by rand()
    limit 50;
```

This is just a guess, because the intention of your query is not obvious to me.

Comment: Why are you doing an order by rand()?

Comment: There's no `order by` in the original query.  This will randomize the order explicitly.  More importantly, it will make it less likely that the same value from `e66` will appear multiple times in the results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff The more proper way is to loop a procedure which inserts the records with count of number of rows in the events table as looping limit.

Comment: I'm new to MySQL and im not 100% sure how this code works but when i try compiling it, gives me this error.[Err] 1052 - Column 'time_stamp' in field list is ambiguous

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your time_test table is not normalized. So, you can use INSERT INTO SELECT statement. With this solution you will copy 100 records from events table.

```
INSERT INTO time_test (unit_66)
SELECT time_stamp
FROM events
WHERE unit_id = 66 LIMIT 50

INSERT INTO time_test (unit_116)
SELECT time_stamp
FROM events
WHERE unit_id = 116 LIMIT 50
```

Comment: That will insert two different rows, one with a blank unit_116 and one with a blank unit_66.

Answer (score -2):

insert into time_test (&unit_66,
&unit_116)
VALUES
(
(select time_stamp from `events`
where unit_id = 66 LIMIT 50),
(select time_stamp from `events`
where unit_id = 116 LIMIT 50)
);
just try this